# How can I omit the code using loop function

Tags: numerical-integration

I would like to compute Integration of $f$ numerically.
But the number of variables are many. The function $f$ depends on $x[1],x[2],\cdots,x[n]$. $n$ is larger than 15. I do not write every element like below.

```
NIntegrate[
  f, 
  {x[1], -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  {x[2], -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  {x[3], -Infinity, Infinity},
…,{x[n], -Infinity, Infinity}
]
```

How can I omit the code using loop function in Mathematica?
I am a beginner of Mathematica Grammer.

Comment: Please, can you explain what you mean by “omit the code”? Do you want to only need to write `x[...]` once? Can you give the form of f, also? How is n determined?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a dupe.

Comment: To CA Trevillian. When you want to add 1 to n in any programming language, you do not have to write, '1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+…+n'. We should use 'for loop' or 'while loop'. I want to find better way to write the code. n is defined by me.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var = Array[x,n]
sol = NIntegrate[f@@var, Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({#, -Infinity, Infinity} & /@ var)]]
```

Test it:

```
n = 5;
f = (Exp[-#1] + Exp[-#2] + Exp[-#3] + Exp[-#4] + Exp[-#5]) &

var = Array[x,n]
sol = NIntegrate[f @@ var,Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({#, -1, 1} & /@ var)]]
```

Comment: Your `Range` should be inside the `NIntegrate`, if you want to do what OP is asking for

Comment: ah, now it makes sense ;)

Comment: you can also try your hand at some codegolf & use `Range@n` ;)

Comment: Also, when mapping a function of a single variable, the argument can be implied. For example, `x/@Range@5` or `Array[x, 5]`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative inspired on Mr Puh response. Here I am using the new `Splice` instead of `Sequence`:

```
n = 5;
f = (Exp[-#1] + Exp[-#2] + Exp[-#3] + Exp[-#4] + Exp[-#5]) &;


n //
   Range //
   Map[x] //
   {Apply[f], Map[{#, -1, 1} &] /* Splice} //
   Through //
   Apply[Inactive[NIntegrate]] //
   Echo //
   Activate
```

I applied `NIntegrate` inactive to be able to display it before it is evaluated.

Comment: This is interesting, because this is the first time I've seen Mathematica deprecate a symbol (`Splice` in favor of `FileTemplate` as of version 10) and then re-use the symbol as a completely different thing! This seems to me to be a problem!

Comment: Thank you! It works!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
NIntegrate[f, Sequence@@Table[{x[i],-Infinity, Infinity},{i,1,20}] ]
```

works? Here, change 20 to your value of n.

Comment: Thank you. But it does not work...