# Which function names have been re-purposed in Mathematica after being deprecated?

Tags: functions, built-in-symbols

I have just learned about the new function [`Splice`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Splice.html) from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/228284/29734). It turns out that this function used to have a completely different usage! (See below.)

To me, this seems dangerous, to deprecate a symbol and then two versions later introduce completely different functionality to that symbol.  What other symbols in *Mathematica* have been deprecated and then used as the name for a new function?

---

From my copy of Version 11.3:

[image]

Comment: BTW, the output of `WolframLanguageData["Splice"]["Timeline"]` seems incomplete.

Answer (score 12):

The oldest example I can think of is `Medium`.

Version 1.x:

[image: Medium usage]

It got deprecated after version 2, and was then [re-introduced in version 6](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v6/ref/Medium.html); that usage persists to this very day.

I suppose `Accumulate[]` also counts.

Version 1.x:

[image: Accumulate usage]

If the usage looks awfully familiar, this is because it now exists as `FoldList[]`, and `Accumulate[]` was then [repurposed in version 6](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v6/ref/Accumulate.html).

Answer (score 9):

The Wolfram Documentation center provides a useful list:

[Incompatible Changes since Mathematica Version 1](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html).

It has this to say about [Splice](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Splice.html):

> The symbol Splice has a new definition; its previous functionality can be accessed with FileTemplate.

In addition (another change from 12.0 to 12.1):

> CurryApplied and OperatorApplied have superseded the experimental function Curry.

(For historical information on `Total` (which was called `ListSum` before release) see [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/171643/106) by [Anton Antonov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/34008/anton-antonov), who developed the function)

Comment: This list appears to not be exhaustive, in particular the other answers here mention some names that aren't present in this list.

Comment: I think the change from `Curry` to `OperatorApplied` is one of the biggest offenders here. I actually used `Curry` a lot, since I like to code in the tacit style. I really wish I understood why `Wolfram Research` decided to replace a five-letter name with a well-known meaning in computer science, with a 15-letter name whose meaning can only be understood by reading the documentation for it.

Answer (score 8):

**FindCycle** was reused, the output format changed, same for **EdgeList**.

I think the number of renamed/reused function are quite small (I would guess less than 20), though I can not find a comprehensive list.